# I am having trouble with a simple argument dependent lookup / template type inferencing issue

Tags: c++, templates, type-inference, argument-dependent-lookup

I have this snippet of code and I do not understand why the std::cout line is not compiling...  The argument lookup / template argument inferencing seems correct...

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    struct M1
    {
        T x;
    };
};

template<typename T>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, typename A<T>::M1 const &o)
{
    os << o.x;
    return os;
}


int main()
{
    A<int>::M1 a;

    std::cout << a; // This line fails

    return 0;
}
```

BTW I'm trying to do this without a declaring operator<<() as an inline function.

Comment: `T` is in a [non-deduced context](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction). The problem is not that `operator<<` is not found by the name lookup, but that its template parameter can't be automatically deduced.

Comment: This has nothing to do with ADL, there are no namespaces involved.

Comment: How would I create a nonmember operator<<() function that would correctly compile?  I guess that's what I should have asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `T` is in a non deduced context.  C++ will only simple pattern match, it will not invert possibly arbitrary type maps.

Imagine there was a specialization of `A<void>` that set `using M1=A<int>::M1`.  Now both `int` and `void` are valid `T` for your `<<`.  As the problem is intractible in general, C++ refuses to even try: you can only pattern match on direct template arguments of your argument types.

To do what you really want:

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
  struct M1 {
    T x;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, M1 const& m1){
      return os << m1.x;
    }
  };
};
```

Learn to love Koenig operators.

Answer (score 2):

The template parameter `T` of your operator cannot be deduced. However, there is some workaround using some SFINAE magic:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct A {
    struct M1 {
        using type = T;
        T x;
    };
};

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, typename A<typename T::type>::M1>::value, int> = 0>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const T& o)
{
    os << o.x;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    A<int>::M1 a;
    std::cout << a; // This line works
    return 0;
}
```